# Can I use the 'use' keyword with object expressions?

Tags: f#

I'm using an object expression to implement two interfaces. One of the interfaces is IDisposable. I expected to be able to use the 'use' keyword with the results from this object expression, but I get an error:

> Type constraint mismatch. The type
>   IConnMan is not compatible with type
>   IDisposable The type 'IConnMan' is not
>   compatible with the type
>   'IDisposable'

Why do I get this error?

```
let connectionstring = "context connection=true"
let connman () = 
   let conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring)
   conn.Open()
   { new IConnMan with
        member x.Connect () = conn
        member x.Disconnect c = ()
     interface IDisposable with
        member x.Dispose() = 
           conn.Close()
           conn.Dispose()
   }

 ... 

 let f() = 
    use cn = connman() // <-- Error!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *object expression* can have just a single type. The type is the type of the first (main) implemented interface - in your case, that's the `IconnMan` type. F# doesn't allow you to use `use`, because it doesn't statically know that the result of `connman` function is `IDisposable`.

You could create interfaces in the object expression in the opposite order:

```
let connman () = 
  let conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring)
  conn.Open()
  { new IDisposable with
      member x.Dispose() = 
          conn.Close()
          conn.Dispose()
    interface IConnMan with
      member x.Connect () = conn
      member x.Disconnect c = () }
```

Then you could write `use cn = connman()` but you couldn't use functions of `IConnMan` without casting (this is essentially the same as doing what Desco suggests). I don't think there is any nice solution to this problem.

Could your `IConnMan` interface inherit from `IDisposable`?

Comment: I hope they fix this for F# 3.0. The use keyword really should check whether the object implements IDisposable, impliticly or explicitly. As it stands, the use keyword is really only usable with types defined in C# (implicit interface implementations)?

Comment: I will go with your suggestion to have IConnMan inherit IDisposable though. Thanks!

Comment: @Robert: No, the `use` keyword works for any type that is statically known to implement it (e.g. classes declared in F# that implement it). This doesn't rely on implicit/explicit interface implementations. But I agree that fixint this would be nice. Unfortunatelly, the only option is to allow writing `use a = anything` and then dynamically checking if `anything :? IDisposable`.

Comment: @Robert: Allowing obejct expressions to (statically) have several types is another question - this would need some fancy extension to the .NET type system, so it is not likely (in particular, you'd need a type `IDisposable+IConnMan` which would mean that the expression has _both_ types).

Comment: @Tomas - I realized my mistake after I posted the comment. :) But still, even with object expressions, it should already be statically known what types are implemented in the same way a regular type can implement several interfaces?  If I convert the object expression to a regular type, it works as expected.

Comment: Are changes in .NET type system really necessary? Now compiler produces anonymous type that implements specified interfaces and possibly inherits from some given type and the static type of this anonymous class is equal to the main implemented interface. The compiler probably can deal with this class in the same way as it does with user-defined classes, keeping in mind the whole list of implemented interfaces.

Comment: @desco: Yes, it could be done purely in F#, but it would introduce some weird situations. It could use erasure (as units of measure) and some custom attributes, but that would be like Java generics :-).

Comment: @Tomas - I don't see the need for all that. Change the spec to only allow for a class in the first, or main, object expression. Mandate that any following expression in the same object be an interface. I'd say it'd be less weird, and more inline with the rest of .Net

Answer (score 3):

F# spec says:

*Object expressions are statically checked as follows.
First, ty0 to tyn are checked and must all be named types. The overall type of the expression is ty0 and is asserted to be equal to the initial type of the expression. However, if ty0 is type equivalent to System.Object and where ty1 exists, then the overall type is instead ty1.*

so you can use type tests and downcasts or change the sequence of interfaces being implemented so IDisposable will be first

```
let f() = 
    use cn = connman() :?> IDisposable
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I could downcast it to IDisposable, but that has serious usability issues. :)